# Can't minimize commented code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, minimize

Visual Studio (2019) The plus / minus box on side of screen no longer appears so that I can minimize blocks of code that I comment out

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlav1.png) where the plus bar shows up where I have minimized my code for a function
but I have nothing showing up for the /* that is later in the picture

Edit:
Apparently, The comments will minimize outside the c# classes and methods but not inside them:[Commentable Code vs UnCommentable Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62xZA.png)

If there is a way to change this please post an answer!

Comment: Out of interest, what about functions and scopes, can you still minimise those?

Comment: Yes I can (in the picture I have a minimized function)
the problem is that it doesn't show the option to minimize the commented out code even though its the /* commented code */ type with over 20 lines commented out

Comment: Can you minimise multiline `//` comments?

Comment: No, none of the comments can be minimized
but all functions and classes are perfectly fine

Comment: Consider using  [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), but **take several hours to read all the documentation** (and also [this C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced

Is this checkbox checked?

```
Show outlining for comments and preprocessor regions
```

Here is what I have in my VS 2017. Do you use any add-ins that may interphere?

[image: Here is my VS 2017]

NEW OBSERVATION:

The comment outlining works at the global scope, namespace and class, but NOT in the method!

C# style comments (triple slash `///`) work in methods, too.

Comment: It is checked for me

Comment: @Riftrecker please see the image I've added to my answer. I am on a different verfsion, but very much doubt they broke it between 2017 and 2019

Comment: Your right! 
All the code that I want to minimize the code Is in the methods 
(is there any way to "fix" / change this)

Answer (score 1):

You could set `Collapset` in `Tools->Environment->Keyboard`.
[image]

> Ctrl + M, Ctrl + O: Collapse all in the document
>
> Ctrl + M, Ctrl + M: expand/collapse at the caret
>
> Ctrl + M, Ctrl + L: expand all documents